# Java RxJava Emit Items From List Infinitly

Tags: android, delay, rx-java, observable

I want emit items with a specified delay, repeatedly from an arraylist.

```
    Observable.from(saverFileNameList)
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(urlString -> Observable.just(urlString)
                            .delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .doOnNext(urlString1 -> {
                                ...


                            })
            ).repeat()
            .subscribe();
```

This is not working, for some reason, i have set a print log on onNext, and i can see everything is being printed very fast so the delay is not being applied. What am i doing wrong

Comment: How do you want to apply the delay: shift the whole emission or between elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delay the emission of the source by the given amount, you can use the following:

```
Observable.from(saverFileNameList)
.delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.repeat()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(v -> { }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

If you want to have in-between delay, use the following:

```
Observable.from(saverFileNameList)
.zipWith(Observable.interval(5, SECONDS).onBackpressureBuffer(), (a, b) -> a)
.repeat()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(v -> { }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```